# How to use a template class as a template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, parameters, template-templates

I have a class which stores a scalar along with associated physical dimension exponents:

```
template <int L, int M, int T, int C, int K, int S, int I>
class Dimension<L, M, T, C, K, S, I>
{
    ...
}
```

I'd like to build a vector like class (Vec), with static storage, which stores an array of these objects.
I would presume the Vec class template would look something like:

```
template <Dimension<L, M, T, C, K, S, I> D, size_t N>
class Vec
{
    ...
}
```

But this causes an error as the template parameter `D` depends on template parameters (`L`, `M`, `T`, `C`, `K`, `S`, `I`). I have tried a couple of things by brute force but I'm just guessing and would prefer to be shown the correct method by someone with expertise in the matter.

I have seen examples where `template<class>` is inserted into the template arguments, but I don't quite understand what it achieves or even if it's actually applicable. Thanks very much for your help.

Note that I am aware that these class examples have been implemented before, probably in better ways.

Edit: Fixed a typo and changed name of Vec class.

Comment: Have you looked at [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)?

Comment: As I said I know that this kind of thing has been done (for example std::array rather than this vector class) but I'm interested in building my own. I specifically would like the stored class to be constrained to a Dimension<> type, rather than any class T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need `template template` arguments.

Anyway, first of all remember to use the word `struct` (or `class`) for `Dimension`

```
template <int L, int M, int T, int C, int K, int S, int I>
struct Dimension
 { };
```

Second, you can declare a type `vect` (please, not `vector`, that can clash with the standard `std::vector`) as follows

```
template <typename, std::size_t>
struct vect;
```

as receiving a type and an unsigned integer.

Then you can implement a partial specialization (with `std::cout` exaple for the template integer values) as follows

```
template <template <int, int, int, int, int, int, int> class Dim,
         int L, int M, int T, int C, int K, int S, int I, std::size_t N>
struct vect<Dim<L, M, T, C, K, S, I>, N>
 {
   vect ()
    { std::cout << " - L: " << L << " - M: " << M << " - T: " << T
                << " - C: " << C << " - K: " << K << " - S: " << S
                << " - I: " << I << " - N: " << N << std::endl; }
 };
```

You can use this `vect` as follows

```
vect<Dimension<2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17>, 42> v;
```

This works with C++98 also.

If you can use C++11 or newer, you can use variadic arguments so the `vect` specialization can be simplified (a little) as follows

```
template <template <int...> class Dim,
         int L, int M, int T, int C, int K, int S, int I, std::size_t N>
struct vect<Dim<L, M, T, C, K, S, I>, N>
 { /* ... */ };
```

or, using variadic arguments, a little more

```
template <template <int...> class Dim, int ... Is, std::size_t N>
struct vect<Dim<Is...>, N>
 { /* ... */ };
```

but, in this case, it's a little more complicated to use the single `Is...` values.

But, if you can use at least C++11, I **strongly** suggest (following the example of Miles Budnek) the use of `std::array`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, the `template template` arguments make a lot more sense now!

Comment: @Arc - a little suggestion added.